swift 6 concurrency error in NIO mock server "Call to actor-isolated instance method 'getResponse(for:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context"
I'm trying to create a MockHTTPServer using NIO. Trying to make it swift 6 compatible. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to resolve Call to actor-isolated instance method 'getResponse(for:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context which occurs in the MockHTTPHandler. I'm hoping someone will tell me it's simple. Wrapping the offending code in a Task creates a different error: "Task-isolated value of type '() async -> ()' passed as a strongly transferred parameter; later accesses could race" and I couldn't figure out which function call is racing.
fileprivate actor MockHTTPServer {
    private let group: EventLoopGroup
    private let channel: Channel
    let port: Int
    
    private var responses: [String: (HTTPResponseStatus, String)] = [:]
    
    private init(group: EventLoopGroup, channel: Channel) {
        self.group = group
        self.channel = channel
        self.port = channel.localAddress?.port ?? -1
    }
    
    static func start(group: EventLoopGroup) async throws -> MockHTTPServer {
        let server = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            let bootstrap = ServerBootstrap(group: group)
                .serverChannelOption(ChannelOptions.backlog, value: 256)
                .serverChannelOption(ChannelOptions.socketOption(.so_reuseaddr), value: 1)
                .childChannelInitializer { channel in
                    channel.pipeline.configureHTTPServerPipeline().flatMap { _ in
                        let handler = MockHTTPHandler()
                        return channel.pipeline.addHandler(handler)
                    }
                }
            
            bootstrap.bind(host: "localhost", port: 0).whenComplete { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let channel):
                    let server = MockHTTPServer(group: group, channel: channel)
                    channel.pipeline.handler(type: MockHTTPHandler.self).whenSuccess { handler in
                        handler.server = server
                    }
                    continuation.resume(returning: server)
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
        
        return server
    }
    
    func stop() async throws {
        try await channel.close()
    }
    
    func addResponse(for path: String, statusCode: HTTPResponseStatus, body: String) {
        responses[path] = (statusCode, body)
    }
    
    func getResponse(for path: String) -> (HTTPResponseStatus, String)? {
        return responses[path]
    }
    
    private final class MockHTTPHandler: ChannelInboundHandler {
        typealias InboundIn = HTTPServerRequestPart
        typealias OutboundOut = HTTPServerResponsePart
        
        weak var server: MockHTTPServer?
        
        func channelRead(context: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
            let reqPart = unwrapInboundIn(data)
            
            guard case .head(let head) = reqPart else { return }
            
            guard let server = self.server else {
                respond(context: context, status: .internalServerError, body: "Server not found")
                return
            }
            
                if let (status, body) = server.getResponse(for: head.uri) {
                    respond(context: context, status: status, body: body)
                } else {
                    respond(context: context, status: .notFound, body: "Not Found")
                }
        }
        
        private func respond(context: ChannelHandlerContext, status: HTTPResponseStatus, body: String) {
            var headers = HTTPHeaders()
            headers.add(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/json")
            headers.add(name: "Content-Length", value: "\(body.utf8.count)")
            
            let head = HTTPResponseHead(version: .http1_1, status: status, headers: headers)
            context.write(wrapOutboundOut(.head(head)), promise: nil)
            
            var buffer = context.channel.allocator.buffer(capacity: body.utf8.count)
            buffer.writeString(body)
            context.write(wrapOutboundOut(.body(.byteBuffer(buffer))), promise: nil)
            context.writeAndFlush(wrapOutboundOut(.end(nil)), promise: nil)
        }
    }
}


You can read more about this error in this excellent blog. In your example, the compiler is raising error about property weak var server: MockHTTPServer? as It is mutable because var keyword which can introduce data races.

The pointer to the blog post was helpful in that it prodded me to step back and look at the problem. Swift error messages are really unhelpful (reminds me of rust a couple of years go). I had to reason about where races could occur and when I can "hack" swift to make it shutup. Here's what I ended up with in case anyone is interested
fileprivate actor MockHTTPServer {
    private let group: EventLoopGroup
    private let channel: Channel
    private let handler: MockHTTPHandler
    let port: Int
        
    private init(group: EventLoopGroup, channel: Channel, handler: MockHTTPHandler) {
        self.group = group
        self.channel = channel
        self.handler = handler
        self.port = channel.localAddress?.port ?? -1
    }
    
    static func start(group: EventLoopGroup, responses: [String: MockResponse] = [:]) async throws -> MockHTTPServer {
        let handler = MockHTTPHandler(responses: responses)

        let channel = try await ServerBootstrap(group: group)
            .serverChannelOption(ChannelOptions.backlog, value: 256)
            .serverChannelOption(ChannelOptions.socketOption(.so_reuseaddr), value: 1)
            .childChannelInitializer { channel in
                channel.pipeline.configureHTTPServerPipeline().flatMap { _ in
                    return channel.pipeline.addHandler(handler, name: "MockHTTPHandler")
                }
            }
            .bind(host: "localhost", port: 0)
            .get()
        
        let server = MockHTTPServer(group: group, channel: channel, handler: handler)
        return server
    }
    
    func stop() async throws {
        try await channel.close()
    }
    
    nonisolated func getState(for path: String) async -> MockState {
        return handler.state[path]!
    }
    
    private final class MockHTTPHandler: ChannelInboundHandler, @unchecked Sendable {
        typealias InboundIn = HTTPServerRequestPart
        typealias OutboundOut = HTTPServerResponsePart
        
        private let responses: [String: MockResponse]
        var state: [String: MockState]

        init(responses: [String : MockResponse]) {
            self.responses = responses
            // Initialize state for each path
            self.state = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: responses.keys.map { ($0, MockState()) })
        }
        
        func getResponse(for path: String) -> MockResponse? {
            return responses[path]
        }
        
        func channelRead(context: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
            let reqPart = unwrapInboundIn(data)
            
            guard case .head(let head) = reqPart else { return }
            
            if let response = getResponse(for: head.uri) {
                switch response {
                case .value(let status, let body):
                    respond(context: context, status: status, body: body)
                case .function(let function):
                    let response = function(head.uri, &state[head.uri]!)
                    respond(context: context, status: response.0, body: response.1)
                }
            } else {
                respond(context: context, status: .notFound, body: "Not Found")
            }
        }
        
        private func respond(context: ChannelHandlerContext, status: HTTPResponseStatus, body: String) {
            var headers = HTTPHeaders()
            headers.add(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/json")
            headers.add(name: "Content-Length", value: "\(body.utf8.count)")
            
            let head = HTTPResponseHead(version: .http1_1, status: status, headers: headers)
            context.write(wrapOutboundOut(.head(head)), promise: nil)
            
            var buffer = context.channel.allocator.buffer(capacity: body.utf8.count)
            buffer.writeString(body)
            context.write(wrapOutboundOut(.body(.byteBuffer(buffer))), promise: nil)
            context.writeAndFlush(wrapOutboundOut(.end(nil)), promise: nil)
        }
    }
}

struct MockState: @unchecked Sendable {
    private var lock = NSLock()
    var requestCount: Int = 0
    
    mutating func increment() {
        lock.withLock { requestCount += 1 }
    }
}

enum MockResponse: Sendable {
    case value(HTTPResponseStatus, String)
    case function(@Sendable (String, inout MockState) -> (HTTPResponseStatus, String))
}

